# Failed to create registry entry using WiX

Tags: wix

The following code failed to create registry entry on Windows 7.

```
<Component Id='RegistryEntry1' Guid='1BECF977-A7A1-448E-8EC8-843A10E7F6D7' Directory='TARGETDIR'>
  <RegistryKey Root='HKLM'
               Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\AssemblyFoldersEx\SimpleMvvmToolkit_2012.SL"
               ForceCreateOnInstall="yes"
               ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">            
      <RegistryValue Type="string" 
                     Value="C:\Program Files\SimpleMvvmToolkit_2012\Binaries\Silverlight\v5.0\"
                     KeyPath="yes"/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

[image: Registry Snap]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the registry key wasn't created, more likely than not, the Component was not installed. Check a verbose log file from the install, for example:

```
msiexec /i path\to\your.msi /l*v install.txt
```

In that log file you will see lines like:

```
Component: RegistryEntry1; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
```

I expect the `Action` will be `None` or something not `Local`. Then look up in the log file to see why the Component was not installed.

PS: The `ForceCreateOnInstall` and `ForceCreateOnUninstall` are not necessary unless you expect random values to be created under that registry key that you must remove on uninstall.

Comment: Component: RegistryEntry1; Installed: Null;   Request: Null;   Action: Null - This was the output when i was checking the verbose log file. pwhat could be possibly a problem?

Comment: Look higher in the verbose log file for that `Component` both by it's `Id` and by it's `Guid`. There should be a message why the Windows installer disallowed it and that should point you in the right direction to fix the issue.

Comment: @RobMensching I am having the exact same problem, but the verbose log of Microsoft Installer does not include any explanation as to why it was Request: Null. I can't find anything on the Guid nor any more information by the Id. I have the Feature marked as Absent="Allow" and DefaultAction="Install". If I set Absent="Disallow" it works, but then it will throw a UAC box at me when I do not have admin rights. in that case I would have liked it to just skip the feature instead, but how?